# Referenciar un Formulario

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Cuando ejecuto el codigo, al momento de envíar el formulario, por consola me aparece el error "ReferenceError: form is not defined", quisiera ayuda para identificar porque se da esto
Codigo del formulario:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
      <label for="inputUser"> Username </label>
      <input type="text" id="inputUser" name ="inputUser">
      <label for="inpuPassword"> Password </label>
      <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name ="inputPassword">
      <input type="button" id="btnLoginForm" name="btnLoginForm" form="loginForm" value="Login">
    </form>
```

Script para enviar el formulario:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btnLoginForm").click(function(){
        var username = $('#inputUser').val();
        var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: form.attr('action'),
          url: form.attr('method'),
          data: form.serialize(),
          beforeSend:function(){
            $("#btnLoginForm").value('Sending...');
          },
          success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response == true){
              location.href ="indexUser.php";
            }
          },
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `form.attr('action')` estás diciendo que quieres obtener el atributo `action` de un elemento con id `form` o el atributo `attr` de un objeto llamado *form*. En tu caso no tienes ninguno de los dos por lo que te da ese error de elemento indefinido.

Según tienes tu código lo que haría sería capturar el `<form>` con JQuery para poder operarlo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnLoginForm").click(function(){
    var username = $('#inputUser').val();
    var password = $('#inputPassword').val();
    var form = $('#loginForm');//Capturamos el formulario por su ID
    
    //Ahora si podemos acceder a sus atributos, aquí se demuestra:
    console.log('Atributo action: ' + form.attr('action'));
    console.log('Atributo method: ' + form.attr('method'));
    
    $.ajax({
      type: form.attr('action'),
      url: form.attr('method'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      beforeSend:function(){
        $("#btnLoginForm").value('Sending...');
      },
      success:function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if(response == true){
          location.href ="indexUser.php";
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="login.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
  <label for="inputUser"> Username </label>
  <input type="text" id="inputUser" name ="inputUser">
  <label for="inpuPassword"> Password </label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" name ="inputPassword">
  <input type="button" id="btnLoginForm" name="btnLoginForm" form="loginForm" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracia!, tu respuesta me corrigió el error.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el error, la variable `form` no esta definida.

### Solución:

Definir la variable `form` antes de utilizarla

#### Ejemplo:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btnLoginForm').click(function(){

        // ACA definimos la variable "form"
        var form = $("#loginForm");
        $.ajax({
          url: form.attr('action'), // <- ACA la usas
          type: form.attr('method'),
          data: form.serialize(),
          beforeSend:function(){
            $("#btnLoginForm").value('Sending...');
          },
          success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response == true){
              location.href ="indexUser.php";
            }
          },
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

**PD**: En la llamada `ajax` estas pasando mal `url` y `type`